# what to signal to emit from Queue to quit thread when socket or other error occurs

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

On the completion of thread we emit `task_done()` to mark the completion of the thread for a `Queue` object, then in case if a Socket error happens like connection reset by peer then what to emit to mark the exit for thread ?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, accept is so the thread can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better of by using **threading.Event** objects rather than trying to fit another signal into the Queue. Just pass the event to the threads and set the event flag when you are done and make the threads always check the Event or use **threading.Event.wait()** if your threads have nothing better to do.

Check out the example down below.

```
import time
import threading

def main():
    job_done = threading.Event()

    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=job, args=(job_done, "Fe Fye"))
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=job, args=(job_done, "Fo Fum"))

    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()

    time.sleep(2)

    job_done.set()

def job(job_done, message):
    while not job_done.is_set():
        print(message)
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Comment: this the code i am working on : https://bitbucket.org/sanfx/filedownloader/src/b1df53eeeb85057624959f8851128b407b0d9537/python/file_download.py?at=develop

how should i implement what you suggested ?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve comes down to waiting on multiple signals. You can check here [sleeping on two events simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317940/python-threading-can-i-sleep-on-two-threading-events-simultaneously)

Comment: I want to quit on the thread for which i got socket error and leave others go like they are already going on !!

Comment: then call **thread.exit()** in the catch block if you don't want to end the main thread.

Comment: but the queue contains the thread , Do you mean after I do `thread.exit()` I should call `queue.task_done()` ?

Comment: No, you should call **thread.exit()** after you call the **queue.task_done()**. Thread can't continue if it has already exited.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that I will make the thread exit only if the operation times out. however I am starting a thread like this:

`th = threading.Thread(target=self._fileWriteToDisk, args=(saveTo, u, file_name),name="fileWrite_Child",)` so how should I specify timeout here ?