# Python waiting for a queue and an event

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have a queue and an event. I would like to exit the loop when the event is set to True, however there is a queue.get() in the loop which blocks until there is something in it.

How can I abort the waiting of the self._commandQueue.get() when the closeEvent Event flag is set?

Note: I want to avoid depending on the blocking nature of the queue and want to block based on the condition of the queue and the eventflag

```
def _execute(self):
    while not self._closeEvent.isSet():
        nextCommand = self._commandQueue.get()
        self._commandExecutor.execute(nextCommand)
        self._commandQueue.task_done()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need something like the Windows `WaitForMultipleObjects()` call, but the python event and queue API don't offer such a beast (but you could use win32api to use that if you are strictly windows), so if you really need BOTH event sources to be checked in parallel, the answer is 'you cannot without polling (or monkey patching the Event class to allow it)'.

But if you are a bit more flexible, you can arrange something like it, by redefining your command queue a bit. If the command queue is a `PriorityQueue`, you could queue your normal jobs with normal priority and have an extra process queue a 'STOP' token with higher priority, once your event signals.

```
STOP = None

def _execute(self):
    while 1:
        nextCommand = self._commandQueue.get()[1]
        if nextCommand is STOP:
           break
        self._commandExecutor.execute(nextCommand)
        self._commandQueue.task_done()

def wait_for_stop_signal(self):
    self._closeEvent.wait()
    self._commandQueue.put((-1, STOP))
```

Now you run `wait_for_stop_signal` in its own thread, and you have the behaviour you want (but waste one thread instead of polling, pick whats worse for your use case).

Comment: Yes thats what I was trying to figure out. Sad to find out that there isn't such as thing available in the python api :(

Answer (score 4):

`Queue` uses events internally according to
http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Lib/Queue.py#l150 Specifically it uses self.not_empty event which your application could also wait on before attempting a `Queue.get_nowait` call.

As for waiting on several events there's [Python threading: can I sleep on two threading.Event()s simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317940/python-threading-can-i-sleep-on-two-threading-events-simultaneously) question with some code examples.

Comment: The post which you have posted has given another alternative to what schlenk has described. Very useful thanks :)

Comment: Probably not good style to wait on a signal that is an private API detail, in addition, it wouldn't help in this case. But the other threading links are useful, especially the (dirty, monkey patching) version that just redefines what an Event does.

Answer (score 2):

`Queue.get` is a blocking method when it's called without parameters.

From docs:

> Put item into the queue. If optional args block is true and timeout is
>   None (the default), block if necessary until a free slot is available.
>   If timeout is a positive number, it blocks at most timeout seconds and
>   raises the Full exception if no free slot was available within that
>   time. Otherwise (block is false), put an item on the queue if a free
>   slot is immediately available, else raise the Full exception (timeout
>   is ignored in that case).

You need to do something like that:

```
try:
    # If `False`, the program is not blocked, it will throw the Queue.Empty exception.
    my_data = queue.get(False)  
    .....Some Code......
except Queue.Empty:
    my_data = None # or whatever you want
```

More options

1. **get_nowait**:

   Queue.get_nowait()

   which is equivalent to `get(False)`.
2. **Using timeout**:

   my_data = queue.get(True, 5)

   This will try to get for 5 secends if the get will fail (nothing to get) it will raise the same exception `Queue.Empty`

Comment: Yes thats what I want to try and avoid. I dont want it to block/not block based only on the queue and go round the loop forever, I want it to block until the queue is not empty *and* the closeEvent flag is not set

Comment: Then use [`Queue.empty()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.empty) in your `while` condition.

Comment: That wouldnt solve the problem of blocking, it would still go round the while loop. I want it to block until there is something in the queue and the event flag is not set. I think what you have suggested would make the while loop iterate but not block. Also note that the while loop is kind of a while True statement.

Answer (score 2):

I offer these two alternatives, which may suit:

### Solution 1

Put a "magic quit marker" into your queue. I will use None, you can use a special Quit message if desired. This is more or less the same as using priority queue method, but (a) it is a bit simpler, (b) BUT the queue will have to empty up to the marker point, which may or may not be acceptable for you.

For example:

```
# Untested
# Processing thread
def run(self):
    while True:
        msg = self.main_queue.get()
        if msg == None:
            break
        ...do..queue..work...

def shutdown():
    self.main_queue.put(None)
```

### Solution 2

Instead of calling Queue.get straight away. Create an event object that is signalled when either: 
* Something is put in the queue.
* You want to shutdown

Instead of exposing the queue to the outside world, define a method to add to queue:

```
def add_to_queue(self, msg):
    self.main_queue.put(msg)
    self.my_event.set() # Signal the consumer

def shutdown(self, msg):
    self.quit_event.set() # Set an event / condvar / msg to indicate exit
    self.my_event.set() # Signal something has happened.




def run(self)
    while True:
        self.my_event.wait()
        if self.quit_event.is_set()
            break
        msg = self.main_queue.get(False) # Empty exception should not happen here
```

You don't necessarily need a quit event as you can assume an empty queue and a signalled my_event means it's time to quit. Although, I think it's better to explicitly use a proper indicator - message, event, condition var, etc.

Comment: How come this answer is that underrated... solution1 is just optimal!!!