# Is python's 'if' polling?

Tags: python, events, if-statement

I am trying wait for any of multiple multiprocessing events at the same time, so I came up with code like this:

```
if e1.wait(timeout) or e2.wait(timeout):
    # this part will be reached if either of both
    # events is set or the wait timed out
```

It works like the comment says. But how does this work? Is the `if` polling bot methods all the time? Or is it called as soon as one event gets set?

Bonus question: Is there some clever way to adjust the code to wait for any number of events, i.e. a list of events? `if True in [e1.wait(timeout),e2.wait(timeout)]` does not work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only waits for the first one. This is due to python's support of [short circuiting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

Comment: This makes it unusable then. ok, I'll try some other approach that was postet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317940/python-threading-can-i-sleep-on-two-threading-events-simultaneously). I just though I was smarter than that ;)

Comment: The thing I don't get about this short circuting is that the first call does evaluate to `False` until it either times out or gets true, so the second wait-part should get checked anyways - am I missing something?

Comment: It evalutes the first call, if it's `true` it stops, otherwise it evaluates the second call.

Answer (score 0):

Wait on a thread or process is blocking, so it will block the current thread for going future until the timeout or the thread has finished. The semantics of `if` in Python is short circuit, which means that if the first one returns true, then the second one will not be called - simonzack said.

Waiting on a number of threads would be kinda hard to implement and maintain for a variety of threads. I would suggest you to use Message passing, and get each process to send a message to a Queue when it is finished. This way you could just check if the queue was of ´len(n)´, where ´n´ is the number of threads/processes. see more here [Queues in multiprocessing](http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html)