# How to wait for any one, of a list of multiprocessing Events

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Suppose I have a list of Events, I could call

```
event[i].wait()
# Do something
```

to wait for the event at index i.

However when I do this, I wait only for this single event and have no idea what state the others are in. So if I want to check my entire list for the first event to be set I do something like this.

```
    while True:
        for event in events:
            if event.is_set():
                # Do something
```

However this uses a lot of CPU time constantly checking every item. Something the standard wait method on a single Event object avoids. Is there a way in python to check all these events for the first state to change without this strain on CPU?

I *could* use a Queue. But this involves (AFAIK) pickling the queue item  to pass it to the next process. Speed is important in my program and I am using shared ctypes to pass strings from process to process which is a lot faster with the sizes I'm working with. I am using the list of events to signal when a shared ctype string is ready to access.

One way I have thought is to use a Queue but have it contain a very small amount of data such as a simple int to signal a particular ctype is ready. But I wanted to see if there was a better more intuitive way to solve this. And this method seems to take quite a while also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python threading: can I sleep on two threading.Event()s simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317940/python-threading-can-i-sleep-on-two-threading-events-simultaneously)